# replacing a character found after a matching pattern using awk / sed

Tags: awk, sed

I have below type of contents in a file. I want to replace  closing bracket symbol `)` only if it appears after pattern `REFERENCES`

Please note that symbol `)` does not have to be at end of the line

```
cat file1    
ALTER TABLE mytable1
       ADD  ( CONSTRAINT myconst1 FOREIGN KEY (fkeyid)
                             REFERENCES mytable2 ) ;
ALTER TABLE mytable5
       ADD  ( CONSTRAINT myconst1 FOREIGN KEY (fkeyid)
                             REFERENCES mytable6 )
 ;
```

Desired output

```
ALTER TABLE mytable1
       ADD  ( CONSTRAINT myconst1 FOREIGN KEY (fkeyid)
                             REFERENCES mytable2  ;
ALTER TABLE mytable5
       ADD  ( CONSTRAINT myconst1 FOREIGN KEY (fkeyid)
                             REFERENCES mytable6 
 ;
```

I tried few things but no luck

Comment: Can you post your attempts?

Comment: Please provide some more detail or code what you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With sed:

```
sed 's/\(REFERENCE[^)]*\))/\1/' file
```

Strings containing `REFERENCE` followed by non `)` characters up to and excluding next `)` character are captured and output using backreference.

Add the `-i` flag to edit the file in place:

```
sed -i 's/\(REFERENCE[^)]*\))/\1/' file
```

**Edit:**

To remove only when there is no opening bracket:

```
sed 's/\(REFERENCE[^(]*[^()]*\))/\1/' file
```

Comment: however I got into another problem soon after , that is, some of the lines in files where like below                                                                                 ALTER TABLE mytable1
       ADD  ( CONSTRAINT myconst1 FOREIGN KEY (fkeyid)
                             REFERENCES mytable2 (col1) ;                                                                in such cases , I want to preserve both the brackets  , i.e .   for above mentioned 2 lines  bracket ) should not be replaced , it should be replaced only if there was no opening bracket appearing after REFERENCES clause